# Gap Between Edge of Object and Mesh

Tags: mesh, rigid-body-simulation

Im using a rock generator add on to create rocks, and have been looking at collisions between rocks using rigid bodies. I found that the rocks dont actually collide, but come close, this lead me to look at edit mode and look at (what I think is) the mesh of the rock.

[image: Rock Mesh]

This rock generation add on is great for producing lots of rocks quickly, so I dont want to create rocks (up to thousands) individually. Is there a way to remesh this to have the mesh intersect with the actual object? Ive tried the remeshing tools in blender, but these alter the shape of my rock (I dont mind a small change, but the changes were quite drastic)

Comment: When simulating objects with modifiers, you need to set the source as "Final", otherwise the solver uses the undeformed mesh. Or you can apply all the modifiers if you don't want to.

Comment: thank you I think that fixes it (at least on first inspection)